# How CAN I ACCESS SQLITE DATBASE in FRAGMENT AND do CRUD OPERATIONS?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

`

```
    lastNameTxt=lastName.getText().toString().trim();

    gurdNameTxt=guardName.getText().toString().trim();

    gurdNumberTxt=guardNumber.getText().toString().trim();

    morningValue=morning.isSelected()?false:true;

    eveningValue=evening.isSelected()?false:true;

    DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql= "INSERT INTO "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2 +"("+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_2+","+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_3+","+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_3+","+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_4+","+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_5+","+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_6+","+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2_COL_7+") VALUES( '"+firsNameTxt+"','"+lastNameTxt+"','"+gurdNameTxt+"','"+gurdNumberTxt+"','"+morningValue+"','"+eveningValue+"')";

    db.execSQL(sql);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`
***I want to crud opearation in a 
fragement of newset android navigation drawer activity***

Comment: Why should it be different from any CRUD operation done in an Activity?

Comment: @Fantômas Here when we findviewbyid() whe have to get the reference to it    
 ex:```View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, container, false);                              ListView lv=root.findViewById(R.id.student_current_list);```

Comment: Anyhow thank you for answering question.I found the solution to my problem